# search JIRA for issues where assignee = reporter

Tags: jira

I'm trying to do an advanced search in JIRA where the assignee was the reporter.

assignee = reporter doesn't work, it throws this error: 
The value 'reporter' does not exist for the field 'assignee'.

I'm able to do assignee = currentuser() and reporter = currentuser() without issue but of course that doesn't return what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done using JQL. You basically have two option: write a script that performs this search, or use a plugin which enables you to do advanced searches and reports.

The one I use is the (non-free) [ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview) plug-in that provides many powerful capabilities, including advanced search functions. For example, to search for all issues where the assignee is also the reporter, write this in the JQL query:

```
issuefunction in expression("project = FOO", "assignee == reporter")
```